# RSpec's let! equivalent in ActiveSupport::TestCase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, minitest, activesupport

In RSpec you can use `let!(:user) { User.create }` to eager load `:user` variable so it gets created before entering test case. Is there equivalent method in `ActiveSupport::TestCase` ?

Comment: Which Rails/minitest version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since tests in `TestCase` are basically ruby classes, you can always define instance variables to your test in the [`setup`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Unit/TestCase.html#method-i-setup) method (which is the first thing executed in a test):

```
UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = User.create
  end

  test 'my user test' do
    assert_not @user.nil?
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how you could do it (it's not fool-proof, would need to reset the hash on teardown):

```rb
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

  def self.let!(name, &block)
    @@lets ||= {}
    @@lets[name] = block.call
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    super if args.any? || block
    @@lets.fetch(name) { super }
  end

  def respond_to_missing(name, include_private = false)
    @@lets.has_key?(name) || super
  end

  def methods
    super + @@lets.keys
  end
end
```